# How to check if user/app can post on target group wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can post on group / page and user wall, but i don't want my app to show error when posting on selected wall, if the selected wall doesn't allow posting so **is there any way to know that are we able to post on target wall?**

Note: I found two similar questions but they do not pertain to exactly what i want

[1 Application able to post on user's Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148626/application-able-to-post-on-users-wall)

[2 How to check the permission whether a friend allow me to post on his wall or not using php sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485020/how-to-check-the-permission-whether-a-friend-allow-me-to-post-on-his-wall-or-not)

Please discuss in comment before taking any negative action.

Thanks.

Comment: not sure what you are asking. you want to check before posting? or you want to hide error (if any) after posting?

Comment: i want to check before posting

Comment: @bool.dev do you able to answer this question ?

Comment: ok, got that you want to check before posting, but your question is still not clear. 1. who is selecting the wall? the user? 2. will he select his/her own wall, or own page wall, or some other wall? 3. how are you allowing the user to select a target wall? 4. and what's the code you are using to post? i will be able to answer your question when you clear all the doubts i have about your question.

Comment: also mention my username @bool.dev when you reply to my comments, otherwise i don't get notified.

Comment: @bool.dev 1.user select the wall
2.no s/he select group wall 
3.my app have the permissions to post on user, group and page wall

4.`  $response = $facebook->api('/$group_id' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost);` use this code to post on group wall 

the problem is that user able to post on group wall but you known some groups set that only able to post so that user not able to post on that group so is there any way to known are we able to post on that group wall

Comment: +1, btw, if you don't want to show error, what do you want to do?

Comment: @bool.dev actualy i don't want to show him/her error from facebook which is looks technically but i want to show him/her simple message that he dont have the permission to post on this group

Comment: @bool.dev thanks for editing dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to check exactly the way you want, coz the privacy varies, as you have already said. The only privacy setting that can be queried is the `OPEN, CLOSED, or SECRET` of [group](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/), which can be done by calling the graph api:

```
`http://graph.facebook.com/$Group_id`
```

That returns json data that has a field `privacy`, which will be one of `OPEN, CLOSED, or SECRET`.

But on top of that you have settings for groups where you can restrict posting to only *group admins*. And that permission **can not be checked**.

So i think what you'll have to do is check the returned value, i.e `$response` **after** making the post. If the permission is not given, then the returned data looks like this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "Exception",
      "message": "You do not have permission to post in this group."
   }
}
```

Hence you can check if `$response` has "error" field, and inform the user accordingly. Somewhat like this: `if(isset($response['error']))`.

Also check the fql table that represents [groups](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group/) for more info, if you haven't already.

Comment: i know its disappointing, but there's nothing else you can do, i believe.

Comment: its also the good way 




nice idea that "if we get error on posting on target wall we simply show message that 'Sorry non-admins not allow to post on this group' and user doesn't able to known that we already try to post"
I will try this

Comment: yup, since there is no way of knowing before, best to show message after trying. and according to your comment in the question, you can show message after trying also.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how to check if a user has given permission to post on their wall?

```
try {
    // Get the permissions this user has
    $call = $this->facebook->api("/me/permissions");

    // If they have the permission we require ('publish_stream')
    if($call['data'][0]['publish_actions']){
        try{
            // Do your magic here...
            // Also include your access token in the array
            $params = array('message'=> 'hello world');
            $call = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',$params);

        }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            $result = $e->getResult(); // prob no permissions
        }
    }
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    $result = $e->getResult();
}
```

So basically, first check to see if the user has permissions for a particular action, then if they do `$call[data][0]['publish_action']` will be a set to `1 (int)`.

Example output of `$call = $this->facebook->api("/me/permissions");`

```
[installed] => (int) 1
[email] => (int) 1
[publish_actions] => (int) 1
```

I have the above permissions from the user through facebook.

Comment: no i mean how to check that if user have permission to post on selected group wall hopes you some groups have seted that only admins can able to post so that if user try to post on that group which is not possible so how to check this

Comment: Voted up on your answer for your effort